# best way to initialize an array in terms of memory management

Tags: objective-c, arrays

Please see my code below

```
- (void) viewDidLoad()
{
  NSMutableArray *tempArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
  [self setImagesArray:tempArray];
  [tempArray release];

  [self Display];
}

-(void) display
{
  //here I just add objects to imagesArray like
    [self.imagesArray addObject:temp]; //temp is some image
}
```

Now I wanna know that if I release imagesArray in dealloc() will it cause memory leak and is the above way right to initialize an array declared as property.

Thanx in advance.

Comment: Don't post the same question multiple times.

Comment: @NSResponder: My net was res[onding very slowly properly. So it happened. i didn't do it intentionally.

Answer (score 0):

as i understand it your doing it right, by relasing only the image array in dealloc.

Comment: this is the issue itself. If I release the imagesArray in dealloc() then after a prolonged use of the app, the app crashes.

Comment: then your dealloc method is called before your finished using the image array ?